# Sublime Text 3 internal image viewer

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

Would it be possible to create an internal image viewer plugin for Sublime Text 3? I noticed in their forum people have mentioned it not possible for ST2 due to the fact that the API doesn't allow access to the UI and widgets, but just wondered if it was still the case for ST3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 now has a built in image preview.

[image: ST 3056 demonstrating the new transparent checkered background]

It also provides provides simple information about the image such as pixels & size of the image in the status bar. This feature was first introduced in development build 3055 with the build after adding checkered backgrounds for transparent images.

Comment: Excellent, just what I was needing. Is there any doc's on it API or usage? Can't seem to find any on the SublimeText website.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an API for it or not. I can't really find anything either. If you're looking to add more functionality to it you'd probably get a quicker answer on their forums. Update back here if you do find anything :)

Comment: This is something I've always felt was missing in sublime, simple feature but something thats particularly handy from front end devs

Comment: Is there an inline image viewer? As in within the same file?

Comment: Seems to work only for .png. get a "failed to load image" error on anything .jpg. So sad.

Comment: I'm also observing the png-only image previewer behaviour. Has there been any progress in extending this to jpg? It seems to be something to do with encoding according to the console error generated.

Comment: This is pretty nice! It would totally awesome if they will add it also for half scale dimensions, especially mobile (.png) icons where the image is 2 times scaled in the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing yet in Sublime Text 3. It would be nice to preview the image and its dimensions right inside of sublime. For now, you will have to open in finder/browser/whatever you use.