# Sublime Text 3 zoom image in internal viewer

Tags: sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 has had an [internal image viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075242/1391441) for a while now.

Is there a way to zoom in/out of an image displayed in this internal viewer? Either via some option in ST, or using an external package.

I've looked around but I couldn't find any information on this. The shortcut `Ctrl +` and `Ctrl -` only zoom text, not the image.

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing there is no zoom capability.

Here is a request for enhancement from December 2017 mentioning this as one of the features not available and desired.
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-image-viewer/33961